# What is the difference between full end-to-end encryption and end-to-end encryption?

Tags: terminology, end-to-end-encryption

What is the difference between full end-to-end encryption and end-to-end encryption?

Are there any differences between these two terms?

Comment: No. There is no difference.

Comment: If you ever see someone making a distinction between "*something*" and "full *something*", it's a good indication they were not being completely honest about the capabilities of the original thing.

Comment: There is, however, a difference between end-to-end and point-to-point. I was taught end-to-end referred to encryption between end entities, like an encrypted email; while point-to-point meant protecting individual communication hops between points, such as IPSec and VPNs, where the data was decrypted and reencrypted at those intermediate points. Unfortunately, I’ve seen the terms used interchangeably by marketing people, so it’s hard to trust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no difference.** End-to-end encryption simply means that both endpoints share a secret key which is used to encrypt all traffic between them. There is no difference between "full" end-to-end encryption and end-to-end encryption. It's like the (lack of) difference between forward secrecy and perfect forward secrecy. They're just different terms to explain the exact same concept.